# Error launching application that uses .Net framework

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

I'm trying to open a program named "Nexus Mod Manager". This is a program designed to install Skyrim mods via its automatic list.

Anyway, it appears to use .Net framework. I have it installed but I still get this error upon trying to launch:

[image: Error]

What am I doing wrong? The program never launches, and about 10 seconds after receiving the above error, I get another one that looks like this:

[image: Error2]

If anyone knows what I can do to fix this, I'd be grateful.

(I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium on a 64-bit machine.)

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  (1) Sceenshots are great, but (at least) until you get the privilege to post images, please consider transcribing short error messages (i.e., typing them) into your questions.  Provide links to images _also_ if you want.  (2) We have many very specific tags, such as [windows-7], [windows-xp], etc.  Please use the most appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error:

```
XML_E_BADCHARINSTRING - A string literal contained an invalid character.
```

The config file is damaged. Repair .NET 2.0 by running `sfc /scannow`. If this doesn't fix it, copy the config file from `C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_netfx-machine_config_ocm_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.1.7601.17514_none_81fa0191bdd08961` to the folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG` and replace the old config file.

*//Edit:*
Ok, here is the exception you get when the app crashes:

```
Nested exception -------------------------------------------------------------
Exception object: 000000000278f438
Exception type: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
Message: Configuration system failed to initialize
InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException, use !PrintException 000000000278ee68 to see more
StackTrace (generated):
    SP               IP               Function
    000000000052C5B0 000007FEF8FCBEDD System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(System.String)
    000000000052E680 000007FEF8FCE699 System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(System.String)
    000000000052E6B0 000007FEF9057898 System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.RefreshConfig(System.String)
    000000000052E6F0 000007FEF905747D System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(System.String)
    000000000052E730 000007FEE75DD3C6 System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.ReadSettings(System.String, Boolean)
    000000000052E7C0 000007FEE75AB30A System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.GetPropertyValues(System.Configuration.SettingsContext, System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyCollection)
    000000000052E890 000007FEE75AB113 System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertiesFromProvider(System.Configuration.SettingsProvider)
    000000000052E920 000007FEE75DC7E3 System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(System.String)
    000000000052E960 000007FEE75DC6AF System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(System.String)
    000000000052E9C0 000007FEE75DC4FC System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(System.String)
    000000000052EA10 000007FEE75DC43F System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(System.String)
    000000000052EA70 000007FF00170934 Nexus.Client.Program.UpgradeSettings(Nexus.Client.Properties.Settings)
    000000000052EAC0 000007FF00170470 Nexus.Client.Program.Main(System.String[])

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80131902
-----------------

Total 12 exceptions

0:000> !PrintException 000000000278ee68
Exception object: 000000000278ee68
Exception type: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
Message: Unrecognized configuration section system.serviceModel.
InnerException: <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP               IP               Function
    000000000052E580 000007FEF90AADF7 System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean)
    000000000052E5C0 000007FEF8FCEAEA System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
    000000000052E600 000007FEF8FCBD2D System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(System.String)
```

this means that the config entry **system.serviceModel** is missing. I've downloaded the code, compiled it with VS2012 and I can run it without any issues. There is a file called NexusClient.exe.config (in the same folder where the exe is). Mine has the entries:

[image]

Make sure your one has the same entries.

Comment: When you say ".net" folder, what do you mean?  Where would i find this? You didn't specify.

Comment: Look at the picture. It tells you the folder: **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG**

Comment: The first method did nothing, even after reboot, so i tried the second. Now it just goes straight onto 'Nexus Mod Manager has stopped working."

Comment: generate a dump (with taskmgr or ProcessExplorer) of the crashing tool (http://forums.avg.com/us-en/avg-forums?sec=thread&act=show&id=187440) Zip this dump and upload the dump.

Comment: NexusClient.rar (33.9 MB)
https://mega.co.nz/#!flg3xRib!ZxH_LBFuNJPVcQRPifSU3nYCByE9GCwIhhYXFc0Kxvs That's the dump in .rar format.

Comment: this time the Client crashes because the settings can be found in the config (Program.UpgradeSettings method in the CLient). Can you reinstall the tool? The installer should modify the machine.config again (and hopefully this time without corrupting the config file).

Comment: ok, I've added the dump output to my former answer.

Comment: Would you mind opening your config file in notepad, then pasting it's contents here? It'd make life a whole lot easier.

Comment: here is my file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5749744/Dokumente/Superuser/user217809/NexusClient.exe.config

Comment: I copied it and it launched, it asked me what games i have and i gave it Skyrim, it found it, then the window closed. I then got this error: http://prntscr.com/1197kt

Comment: Here is the trace file it dumped: http://pastebin.com/vBn6DEnR

Comment: Did you ever got it working before? The log shows that this error occurred: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx . Do what you see in the screenshot and create a bugentry on their website.